# Java free spot pieces

Tags: java, javafx

I have a piece that needs to get surrounded by other grey pieces if the coordinate around the piece is not used.

I tried to do the following:

```
public List<Piece> boardPiece(){
    List<Piece> boardPieces = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Piece pieces : listToPiece) {
        if (pieces.getCoordinate() != null){
                boardPieces.add(pieces);
        }
    }
    return boardPieces;
 }

public List<Coordinate> getSurroundings() {
     List<Coordinate> surroundings = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Piece boardpieces : boardPiece()) {
         for (Coordinate coordinate : makeDirections()) {
            surroundings.add(new Coordinate(boardpieces.getCoordinate().getRow() + coordinate.getRow(), boardpieces.getCoordinate().getColumn() + coordinate.getColumn()));
         }
     }
     return surroundings;
}

public List<Coordinate> makeDirections(){
      directions.add(new Coordinate(1,-1));
      directions.add(new Coordinate(-1,1));
      directions.add(new Coordinate(-1,0));
      directions.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
      directions.add(new Coordinate(0,-1));
      directions.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
      return directions;
    }
```

A boardpiece is a piece that is on the board and that has a coordinate. A boardpiece who doesn't have a coordinate shouldn't be surrounded by other grey pieces. In my drawer the following I have written the following code:

```
public void drawEmptyPieces() {
    for (Coordinate emptyPiece : emptyPieces) {
        EmptyPiece emptyPiece1 = new EmptyPiece(new Coordinate(emptyPiece.getRow(), emptyPiece.getColumn()));
        emptyPiece1.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        emptyPiece1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gameField.getChildren().add(emptyPiece1);
    }
}
```

I tried to avoid that grey pieces are drawed over boardpieces:

```
public void drawEmptyPieces() {
    for (Coordinate emptyPiece : emptyPieces) {
        for (Piece pieceObjects : pieces){
            if (pieceObjects.getCoordinate().getRow() != emptyPiece.getRow() && pieceObjects.getCoordinate().getColumn() != emptyPiece.getRow()){
                EmptyPiece emptyPiece1 = new EmptyPiece(emptyPiece);
                emptyPiece1.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                emptyPiece1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                gameField.getChildren().add(emptyPiece1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm confused about `new Coordinate(emptyPiece.getRow(), emptyPiece.getColumn())` ... An `emptyPiece` is a `Coordinate`, and you are creating a new `Coordinate` that is the same as the old `Coordinate`.  So you are just creating a `Coordinate` that is a duplicate of the other?  Assuming coordinates are immutable, you could have just done `new EmptyPiece emptyPiece1 = new EmptyPiece(emptyPiece);`?   Or what am I missing?

Comment: @AJNeufeld I could've done that and it would've been better. Didn't see it yet. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you have provided enough information to answer your problem.  But here are a few thoughts.

---

`makeDirections()` is either broken (missing declaration of `directions` local variable), or broken because it keeps adding 6 new `Coordinate` objects to a `directions` field each time it is called.  In either case, it is doing more work than needed.  Consider instead:

```
private final static List<Coordinate> directions;

static {
    List<Coordinate> dirs = new ArrayList<>();
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(1,-1));
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(-1,1));
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(-1,0));
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(1,0));
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(0,-1));
    dirs.add(new Coordinate(0,1));
    directions = Collections.immutableList(dirs);
}

public static List<Coordinate> makeDirections() {  // or getDirections()
    return directions;
}
```

---

`getSurroundings()` looks like it can (will?) add the same `Coordinate` to surroundings multiple times.  If a piece is at `[5,5]`, and another piece is at `[7,5]`, you will add `[5,5]+[1,0]` and `[7,5]+[-1,0]` to surroundings.  There may even be a piece at `[6,5]` which will also add `[5,5]` and `[7,5]` to surroundings as well.

Instead ...

Ensure `Coordinate` implements `equals` and `hashCode`, so two `Coordinate` objects with the same row and column are equal, and both hash to the same value.  Then, in `getSurroundings()` use:

```
Set<Coordinate> surroundings = new HashSet<>();
```

So that `surroundings` only contains each coordinate once.  Before returning, you could remove all "occupied" coordinates from the surroundings.

```
for (Piece piece : pieces) {
    surroundings.remove(piece.getCoordinate());
}
```

You could return the set instead of a list, or if you want to keep it as a list:

```
return new ArrayList<>(surroundings);
```

Without "surroundings" containing duplicates and coordinates where existing pieces are, you may find drawing your board much, much easier.

---

Unless you game board is infinite in extents, you will be creating `Coordinate` objects beyond the edges of you board.  Consider adding the method `getNeighbours()` to the `Coordinate` class:

```
class Coordinate { 
    public Collection<Coordinate> getNeighbours() {
        List<Coordinate> neighbours = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for (Coordinate dir: getDirections()) {
            Coordinate n = new Coordinate(getRow() + dir.getRow(), getColumn() + dir.getColumn());
            if (n.isValid()) {
                neighbours.add(n);
            }
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
}
```

Then `getSurroundings` becomes a little simpler, with:

```
for (Piece boardpieces : boardPiece()) {
    surroundings.addAll(boardpieces.getCoordinate().getNeighbours());
}
```

Without any "surroundings" being off the board.

---

A "Direction" is not a `Coordinate`.  They are used for different things.  A `Coordinate` is a position on the board, where as your "Direction" is a relative offset.  The board may have constraints that row and column values must be between (say) 0 and 20; your "Direction" objects have negative row and column values; which would violate those constraints.  This means you could not add proper checking and `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid coordinate")` in the constructor of `Coordinate` if given a bad value.

I would create a new class for `Direction` objects.  Actually, I'd use `enum Direction { ... }`.  Then `Direction.values()` would return the set of all directions -- you wouldn't need to create the set yourself.  This is a much larger change than other ones, and may have consequences beyond the small subset of code you provided.  A good change, but perhaps a lot of work.

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you so much! @AJNeufeld